# Retain decimal portion of value in seq command?

Tags: bash, shell, seq

I'm working on a script that needs to locate an Apple SDK for cross-compiling from the command line. The [SDK names have a particular format and it includes a version number](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cryptopp-users/8Z0qfwAjSbA/nKYbhTNBBgAJ):

- iPhoneOS7.0.sdk
- iPhoneOS7.1.sdk
- iPhoneOS7.2.sdk

When I run the following script using [the ***`seq`*** command](http://ss64.com/bash/seq.html), the decimal portion is dropped when the decimal portion is 0. That is, ***`6.0`*** is displayed as ***`6`***. The other values are OK:

```
for i in $(seq 20.0 -0.1 4.3)
do
   echo "Value: $i"
done
```

For example:

```
$ ./count.sh 
Value: 20
Value: 19.9
Value: 19.8
Value: 19.7
Value: 19.6
Value: 19.5
Value: 19.4
Value: 19.3
Value: 19.2
Value: 19.1
Value: 19
...
```

I'm not sure if ***`seq`*** is not producing the trailing 0, or if ***`echo`*** is dropping the trailing 0. In either case, I need to retain it.

How do I retain the decimal portion of the value ***`i`***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[seq(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/seq) takes a [printf(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) style formating strings with the argument `-f`, so you can do `seq -f "%.1f" 20.0 -0.1 4.3`.

Which gives:

```
$ seq -f "%.1f" 1 0.1 2
1.0
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.6
1.7
1.8
1.9
```